# What date format is this?

Tags: c, date

I am trying to query some data out of [Home Bank](http://homebank.free.fr/) using the data file it produces.

This is a transaction that appears in the file:

```xml
<ope date="734309" amount="-14.24" account="4" dst_account="0" paymode="0" flags="1" payee="239" category="2" wording="" info="" tags="" kxfer="0" />
```

I am interested in the `date="734309"`. I've not seen this format before so don't know how to parse it.

The application is written in C if that is any help.

Comment: Do you know if it's supposed to be a date? A time? A datetime?

Comment: Don't they document their file format? It should tell you what format the date is in.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=734309+timestamp) returns `11:58:29 am UTC  |  Friday, January 9, 1970`. I don't think that date is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

734309 / 365 = 2011.80548

So I guess it's something like "days since 1 January in the year 1". If you know the actual date that that number should represent, you can reconstruct the precise offset from there.

Comment: Yeah, my coder's fingers typed a nice round number somehow... fixed it way before your comment though ;)

Comment: Thanks very much! Using ruby I calculated the actual date -  Date.new(1,1,1) + 734309 -  20 June 2011 :)

Comment: But don't use it to go back to the Middle Ages: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the result of the SQL [`TO_DAYS()`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/DaysSince1AD.htm) function, which represents the number of days since the first day of 1 A.D.  (I don't know whether `TO_DAYS()` is specific to MySQL or if it's a standard SQL function.)